# Django ManyToManyField referenced in loop

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

My problem looks like this - I have many to many field that I need to reference multiple times in the loop. Each time I have to do it with another id. Every solution I can think of seems pretty heavy and I want to do it nice and clean I'm just out of the ideas (the problem is probably my little experience with Django and Python).
Right now I have something like this (it obviously doesn't work):

```
    projects = Project.objects.order_by('name').values()
    for project in projects:
        currentProject = Project.objects.get(pk=project['id'])
        projects[index] = {
            'genres': currentProject.genres.all().values()
        }
     context = {
     'projects': projects,
     }
```

I have been looking for the answer for like 2 hours now and couldn't find what I was looking for so I hope someone here can give me some advices. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need to use [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related),

```
projects = Project.objects.prefetch_related('genres_set')
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you are trying is to create a 2d list of genres of all projects sorted by their name. Then do,

```
 projects = [list(cur_project.genres.all()) for cur_project in Project.objects.all().order_by('name')]
```

Comment: I tried this one but now I'm getting this:
Reverse for 'project' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['projects\\/(?P<id>[0-9]+)\\/$']
:(

Comment: Isn't that error related to urls. Can you upload the whole error, then maybe I will be able to help you

Comment: I solved it but anyway I used other solution :). Thanks for help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If i were you i would isolate the ids,
and use this:

```
projects= Projects.objects.filter(id__in=list_of_ids)
```

It returns multiple objects for the given ids.